# How I can add the same text to several files via script?

Tags: bash, shell, ed

I want a simple way to add the same text (e.g. "bye" or more lines) to a group of files using a small script. I tried something with `ed` and `vi` inside of a script, but it did'nt work.

**Edit**: I edit this coment to be more specific:

I have the files c0001.gin c0002.gin ... up to let's say 500. I need to add to the end of each file the next text:

```
species
Ca    core  2.00000000
Co    core  2.00000000
C     core  1.34353898
O     core  1.01848700
O     shel -2.13300000
buck intra
O     core O     core  4030.3000     0.245497 0.00000000      0.00  2.50 1 0 0
buck
Ca    core O     shel  2154.0600     0.289118 0.00000000      0.00 10.00 1 0 0
Co    core O     shel  1095.6000     0.286300 0.00000000      0.00 10.00 1 0 0
Ca    core C     core 120000000.000  0.120000 0.00000000      0.00 10.00 1 0 0
Co    core C     core  95757575.760  0.120000 0.00000000      0.00 10.00 1 0 0
buck inter
O     shel O     shel  64242.454     0.198913  21.843570      0.00 15.00 1 0 0
morse intra bond
C     core O     core 5.0000000     2.5228      1.19820  0.0000 1 0
three
C     core O     core O     core 1.7995     120.00
outofplane bond intra
C     cor O     cor O     cor O     cor 8.6892 360.0
spring
O      52.740087
```

I want just a script to do that.

Furthermore, the files are in folder called "CALCS" and  I wanted to move each file to another folder inside CALCS called "001" for c0001.gin, "002" for file c0002.gin and so on.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Something like `for file in <files> ; do echo "<something>" >> "${file}" ; done`.

Comment: @Biffen Some error happen with this.

Comment: Oh, ‘*some error*’, eh? Well, use *some* solution.

Comment: @Biffen -bash: syntax error near unexpected token `<'. Sorry for my english, not everyone speak english fluently.

Comment: `<files>` and `<something>` are meant to be replaced. Since you've not told us to *which* files you want to write you'll have to do that bit yourself.

Comment: So, as @Biffen says, if you want to add the words "grey tails" to all files whose names begin with "elephant"... `for f in elephant*; do echo "grey tails" >> "$f" ; done`

Comment: Right!! I'll try this. Thank you very much.

Comment: Visualize @Biffen slowly turned toward the wall softly banging his head against said wall... ...

Comment: git - this whole swarm of confusion is caused by the failure to provide a concise example of your code which we here can verify and make suggestions from. We all suffer from the same limitations -- we cannot see what is on your screen... That's where you have to help us

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin Desk. And not that softly. Glad someone understands. 

Comment: Ok I´ll edit. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#!/bin/sh

text="${1:?Usage: $0 <text> <file>...}"
shift
files="${@}"

for file in $files
do
    echo "$text" >> "$file"
done
```

Comment: Gracias al rescate. I`ll try this solution.